# ReflectionException in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php error in creating request validation - Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I have some problems with my code. I am following the tutorial in Laravel 5. I am doing the form validation but I got this error and I don't know how did it happened. I am new to Laravel.

I am creating the article sample.

Here's my controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

//use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;
//use Request;

class ArticlesController extends Controller {

    public function index() {

        //$articles = Article::all();
        //$articles = Article::latest('published_at')->where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now())->get();
        /** select * from articles where published_at <= now() order by published_at desc */

        $articles = Article::latest('published_at')->published()->get();

        return view('articles.index', compact('articles'));

    }

    public function show($id) {

        $article = Article::findOrFail($id);

        //dd($article->published_at);

        return view('articles.show', compact('article'));

    }

    public function create() {

        return view('articles.create');

    }

    public function store(CreateArticleRequest $request) {


        //$input = Request::all();
        //$input['published_at'] = Carbon::now();
        //$title = Request::get('title');

        Article::create($request->all());

        return redirect('articles');

    }

}
```

Here's my Request

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class CreateArticleRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true; //permissions
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|min:3',
            'body' => 'required',
            'published_at' => 'required|date'
        ];
    }

}
```

My Route:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);

Route::get('articles','ArticlesController@index');
Route::get('articles/create','ArticlesController@create');
Route::get('articles/{id}','ArticlesController@show');

Route::post('articles','ArticlesController@store');
```

When I checked it doesn't allow me to insert in the database.

Comment: 'When I checked it doesn't allow me to insert in the database' -> please clarify wht you mean.  Error message?  Simple 'nothing happens'?  Also how are you sending your request?

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing ReflectionException because you are using wrong class. You should use `App\Http\Requests\CreateArticleRequest` instead of `App\Http\Requests` in `ArticlesController`

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the **CreateArticleRequest** you are using in the **controller file which is using it**

Add this line after `use Carbon\Carbon;`

`use App\Http\Requests\CreateArticleRequest;`

It will include your request file in the controller